# sql query, how to select open session

Tags: sql, join

I have table named `sessions` that `select` query return this:

```
id    name    state
--------------------
1     n1      open
2     n2      open
3     n1      close
4     n3      open
```

I want a query that returns just open sessions. (`n2` and `n3`).
I tried `inner join` sessions table with himself but didn't works...

Comment: is the id order important? What if several open, and less number of close? etc. Add more sample data, to complicate things - and adjust the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable AS t1
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name 
           AND t2.state = 'close'
WHERE t1.state = 'open' AND t2.id IS NULL
```

The above query returns all `'open'` records with no matching `'close'` state record.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f38be/2)

Answer (score 0):

Return a name if the state is open, and no later id has same name but closed state:

```
select distinct name
from sessions s1
where state = 'open'
  and not exists (select 1 from sessions s2
                  where s2.name = s1.name
                    and s2.state = 'close'
                    and s2.id > s1.id)
```